# Batch file with a recursive for loop to move file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am trying to create a batch script to move files base on search criteria into another folder of the same subfolder structure.

Tried the following but the result is not quite right.

```
for /r "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\" %%x in (Test*.txt) do move "%%x" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\"
```

As it is showing:

```
move "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub1\Test1.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\"
move "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub2\Test1.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\"
```

I would like the outcome to be the following:

```
move "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub1\Test1.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\Sub1\Test1.txt"
move "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub2\Test1.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\Sub2\Test1.txt"
```

How will I be able to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: This can also be done very easily with forfiles (native cmd command) try forfiles /? for what it can do.

Comment: @LPChip I was curious, how to use `forfiles` to move several files in folders from different sources
and to selective destinations in a simpler way? I would like to know, would you mind answering? I don't use `forfiles` a lot, I think it would be good/useful to know that.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@echo off 

for /D /R "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\" %%I in (*)do pushd "%%~I" & (
    2>nul >nul mkdir "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\%%~nxI" 
    move "%%~I\Test*.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\%%~nxI" & popd
   )
```

- Outputs command loop results:

```py
move "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub1\test_001.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\Sub1\test_001.txt"
move "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub1\test_002.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\Sub1\test_002.txt"
move "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub1\test_003.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\Sub1\test_003.txt"
move "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub2\test_001.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\Sub2\test_001.txt"
move "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub2\test_002.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\Sub2\test_002.txt"
move "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub2\test_003.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\Sub2\test_003.txt"
```

- The `move` command results:

```py
c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub1\test_001.txt
c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub1\test_002.txt
c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub1\test_003.txt
        3 file(s) moved.
c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub2\test_001.txt
c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub2\test_002.txt
c:\Test_Copy\Source1\Sub2\test_003.txt
        3 file(s) moved.
```

**Obs.:** If all your subfolders **`c:\Test_Copy\Target1\Sub[n]`** already exist, remove line **`2>nul >nul mkdir "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\%%~nxI"`**

```py
@echo off 

For /D /R "c:\Test_Copy\Source1\" %%I in (*)do pushd "%%~I" & (
    move "%%~I\Test*.txt" "c:\Test_Copy\Target1\%%~nxI" & popd
   )
```

- Try using `for /D /R`:

```py
FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
```

The option **`/D /R`** is **undocumented**, but can **be a useful combination**, while it **will recurse through all subfolders** the wildcard   will only match against **Folder/Directory names** (not filenames)

**[Source linked to **ss64.com**](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

```py
Rem :: Set your folder /Directory /Recursively tree starting at "c:\Test_Copy\Source1"
For /D /R "c:\Test_Copy\Source1"
```